# Copy(or repeat) a page of source pdf into another pdf using java PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have a **template.pdf** which has header and footer(some text/image). I am generating a new pdf (say **result.pdf**) which has other data. I need to copy/repeat **template.pdf** on every page of **result.pdf**. So basically the **template.pdf** will act as header and footer on every page of **result.pdf**.

The problem is **template.pdf** appears only on 1st page of **result.pdf**. My **result.pdf** can be any 'n' number of pages.

```
public class templateTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
   File file = new File("template.pdf");
   PDDocument mainDocument = PDDocument.load(file);     

    PDPage myPage = mainDocument.getPage(0);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(mainDocument, myPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true);

    contentStream.beginText();
    // Some text
    // Table 1 (Depending on table 1 size, pdf pages will increase) 

    contentStream.endText();
    contentStream.close();

    mainDocument.save("result.pdf");
    mainDocument.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: LayerUtility may be what you need.

Comment: @Tilman Can you please share one example or URL of the LayerUtility?

Comment: Just enter LayerUtility into the search box. Or try the SuperimposePage example from the source code download. (Sorry, it's 3am here, I couldn't sleep and now I'm going back to bed)

Comment: Were you able to use LayerUtility (specifically, the `importPageAsForm` method)? If yes, please delete this question. If no, please edit it to explain what didn't work or why LayerUtility isn't the thing for you.

Comment: Thank you Tilman, LayerUtility did work for me. I am keeping this question and have posted the answer, just in case if anybody in future have similar type of problem they can refer it from here directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered my own question. Tilman Hausherr pointed me in the right direction.

```
public class templateTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 

   File file = new File("template.pdf");
   PDDocument templatePdf = PDDocument.load(file);
   PDDocument mainDocument = new PDDocument();     

   PDPage myPage = new PDPage();
    mainDocument.addPage(myPage);
   PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(mainDocument, myPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true);

   contentStream.beginText();
   // Some text
  // Table 1 (Depending on table 1 size, pdf pages will increase) 

  contentStream.endText();
  contentStream.close();

  // Process of imposing a layer begins here
  PDPageTree destinationPages = mainDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();

  LayerUtility layerUtility = new LayerUtility(mainDocument);

  PDFormXObject firstForm = layerUtility.importPageAsForm(templatePDF, 0);

  AffineTransform affineTransform = new AffineTransform();

  PDPage destPage = destinationPages.get(0);

  layerUtility.wrapInSaveRestore(destPage);
  layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(destPage, firstForm, affineTransform, "external page");

  mainDocument.save("result.pdf");
  mainDocument.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: This was a very helpful example! Thanks for taking the time to post it up. Unfortunately the layer included from the template.pdf with the header and footer seems to overwrite the content in the ContentStream? I have a 2 page template.pdf which has a header and footer on both pages. I specify the first page in the importPageAs form call but I can't seem to set the z-layer number on the import to put the template page below the contentStream? Any ideas?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: @Mark please make that a stack overflow question in its own right (with a link to this question for some backgrounds).

Comment: I got it sorted, I think the problem was that firstly the template PDF file had two pages which even though I specified the first one, it was putting it in twice and second was that I wasn't using the ContentStream in AppendMode.APPEND.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been struggling with adding multiple pages based on a single page template (header/footer).  This got me there!  Now if I could just understand what an AffineTransform is and why it did what it did to make it work... but I'll just imagine it is like the `stamp` function of the `pdftk` toolset